# webpack config to add a folder for icons

Tags: javascript, css, svg, webpack

I have a icons folder with multiple SVG files and I want to add those so i can use those svg files in my localhost app.

but I am not how to use them below is the webpack configuration. after complie it generated the final application.js and application.css files inside priv folder

```
-->priv
   -->css
      --> application.css
   -->js 
      --> application.js
```

I want to add one more folder inside this priv

```
-->priv
   -->css
      --> application.css
   -->js 
      --> application.js
   -->asserts
      --> first folder
          -->few svg files
     --> another folder
         --> few svg files
```

webpack.config.js file

```
//webpacks neat!
'use strict';

var path = require('path');
var ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');
var webpack = require('webpack');

function join(dest) { return path.resolve(__dirname, dest); }

function web(dest) { return join('web/static/' + dest); }

var config = module.exports = {
    devtool: 'eval',
  entry: {
    application: [
      web('css/application.sass'),
      web('js/application.js'),
      web('assets/'),
    ],
    transactions: [
      web('css/application.sass'),
      web('js/transactions.js')
    ]
  },

  output: {
    path: join('priv/static'),
    filename: 'js/[name].js',
  },

  resolve: {
    extensions: ['', '.js', '.sass', '.css'],
    modulesDirectories: ['node_modules'],
  },

  module: {
    noParse: /vendor\/phoenix/,
    loaders: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        loader: 'babel',
        query: {
          cacheDirectory: true,
          plugins: ['transform-decorators-legacy'],
          presets: ['react', 'es2015', 'stage-2', 'stage-0'],
        },
      },
      { 
        test: /\.css$/, 
        loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract("style-loader", "css-loader") 
      },
      {
        test: /\.sass$/,
        loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract('style', 'css!sass?indentedSyntax&includePaths[]=' + __dirname +  '/node_modules'),
      },
      { 
        test: /\.(png|woff|woff2|eot|ttf|svg)$/, 
        loader: 'url-loader?limit=100000' 
      },{
      test: /\.svg$/,
        loader: 'svg-inline'
      }
    ],
  },

  plugins: [
    new ExtractTextPlugin('css/application.css')
  ],
};

if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
  config.plugins.push(
    new webpack.optimize.DedupePlugin(),
    new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({ minimize: true })
  );
}
```

I put the asserts folder inside the priv folder but still I am not able to access those svg files inside asserts folder.

Any suggestion how to access those in local server?